# Cant FETCH data (TypeError: Failed to fetch)

Tags: javascript

I used Node, Express and MongoDB to create simple API that should allow me get JSON data, next I deployed it on Heroku.

Whenever I tried to fetch it (locally or using Heroku link), I received this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
This is my code:

```
async function fetchFlats () {
const res = await fetch("https://rocky-basin-55272.herokuapp.com/");
const data = await res.json();
console.log(data);
}
fetchFlats()
```

Comment: Read the **other** error messages, not just the last one.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. The link that you provided was a good read and pointed me in the right direction. I used [cors - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and everything works fine.